# How setState() redraw the new state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, callback, setstate

How setState() function redraw the new state after quick changes in statefull management in Flutter

It easily redraw the new state but how this concept work?
I am beginner in Flutter

Comment: @HunterBooks he's just asking for the concept behind `setState` function

Answer (score 0):

According to Flutter Documentation,

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of
> this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface
> in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for
> this State object.

So if you want to update the state of a widget then you need to use a `setState` function. Though you must have a `Stateful` Widget in order to use it as a widget's state can't be changed in a `Stateless` Widget. You can read more about it on [Flutter Website](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html#:%7E:text=Calling%20setState%20notifies%20the%20framework,build%20for%20this%20State%20object.)

Answer (score 0):

Statefull widgets are obvious in flutter, these widgets are immutable but their states are mutable, they can change,

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

When you finally run your APP, you create a widget tree and for that widget tree flutter creates a corresponding element tree,

So when you call setState, the flutter framework checks for changes in widget tree and and updates corresponding element tree,

****Flutter framework is so smart that without building whole element tree from the scratch, it just updates it as per changes in widget tree.

***To get more performance benefit keep the state deeper inside the widget tree so the parents remain unaffected while flutter framework update the element tree.